# Find the latest created dir and rename it -Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I have a situation where i have to rename the dir name if condition matches :

Condition : 
value=`cat /sys/kernel/debug/spmi/spmi-0/data | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 14`

`If (Value == 20)` then
Rename the latest Created dir with `"xyz_test"`

So far i could able to search the latest dir from below command

```
ls -1tr * | tail -1
```

but How to rename it? I am very new in shell scripting so not getting that much idea.

Comment: You can rename something by moving it (`mv`).

Comment: can you please give an example i mean small code that would be relly helpful for me

Comment: Well `mv "$orig" "$newname"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a simple script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash   
# name this file: script.sh                                                                  
condition=`cat /sys/kernel/debug/spmi/spmi-0/data | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 1\
4`

if [ $condition = 20 ]
then
    last_created_dir=`ls -tAF | grep '/$' | head -1`
    mv $last_created_dir xyz_test
fi
```

then run it with

```
bash script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the name of the newest folder by:

```
last_one=`ls -1td */ | head -1`
```

and then you can use this variable to change the name:

```
mv "$last_one" "xyz_test"
```